# Mysql via Java callable statement inserts escape character \ also in db

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysql-error-1064, callable-statement

```
 cs==com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement@b626b0: CALL insert_new_folder('test\'share\'today16102014','',1299,'Y','N','N',0,0)
```

From java it inserts like **test\'share\'today16102014** but from mysql command line it inserts like **test'share'today16102014**. How to make java inserts like **test'share'today16102014.**

Comment: Can you show the java code?

Answer (score 0):

use '' to replace \'

```
.. values ('test''share''today16102014','',1299,'Y','N','N',0,0)
```

Comment: it doesn't work as of now...because i am dealing with large datas